# How to define User Access Levels in PHP

Tags: php, acl

I'm working on project where I've to define different user levels so that a user can access only assigned sections.

How can I do this?

Comment: and watch this video too (ACL is dead by Zed Shaw): http://vimeo.com/2723800

Answer (score 2):

You can manage it by define `role_id` and permissions into a table
for example you can create table permission and define relation like :-

| user_id | role_id | module_id | view | edit | delete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1(admin) | 2(view) | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2(marketing) | 3(user list) | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Check role permission after user logged in.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

give the User a roleid，then you judge the id number